# LDA, PCA and k-means: how are they related?

Tags: pca, multivariate-analysis, k-means, discriminant-analysis

I am trying to understand how linear discriminant analysis (LDA) is related to principal component analysis (PCA) and k-means clustering method. As an example, here is a comparison between PCA and k-means:

[image]

My question is how LDA is related to PCA and k-means?

Comment: Where is the snapshot taken from? By the way, it does not look much of a *comparison* between k-means and PCA to me; it shows two different formulas, yes, but how do they compare?..

Comment: See also: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23353/pca-lda-cca-and-pls, http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/87509/4598

Answer (score 1):

I'm by no means an expert in the topic, but it seems that K-means clustering can be viewed as a *dimensionality reduction* technique, of which LDA and PCA are *direct* examples. Clustering via K-means seems to uncover the **latent structure** of data, which essentially results in dimensionality reduction. I'm sure that other people will provide some more advanced answers to this question.

Additionally, I would like to share two **references** that are *relevant* to the question/topic and IMHO are rather comprehensive. One reference is a highly-cited [research paper](http://ranger.uta.edu/~chqding/papers/KmeansPCA1.pdf) by Ding and He (2004) on the relationship between **K-means and PCA** techniques. Another reference is a [research paper](http://www2.ece.ohio-state.edu/~aleix/pami01.pdf) by Martinez and Kak (2001), presenting the comparison between **PCA and LDA** techniques.

**References**

Ding, C., & He, X. (2004, July). K-means clustering via principal component analysis. In *Proceedings of the twenty-first International Conference on Machine Learning* (p. 29). ACM.

Martínez, A. M., & Kak, A. C. (2001). PCA versus LDA. *IEEE Transactions on Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence, 23*(2), 228-233.

Comment: See stackoverflow.com/a/29731291/2056067 for an attempt to summarize Ding & He. :-)

Comment: @A.Donda: Thank you for the link. :-) Both answers are very nice (+1) and I will re-read them, when I'll have a bit more time. However, I think that particular question belongs to either _Cross Validated_, or _Data Science_ SE site and, therefore, should be migrated.

Comment: Maybe so, the line is not very clear for programming-related statistics questions (or vice versa). You can flag the question for moderator attention. DS SE is still in beta though. :)

Answer (score 0):

LDA & PCA are used just in different circumstances.

Clustering & PCA are unsupervised. LDA is supervised. - [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/514229/347139) is good explanation of differencies b/w unsupervised & supervised methods.

The main aim of Clustering, as part of EDA, is grouping... or even if outliers are forming Gaussian mixture => Novelty appearance in ds (e.g. compared with another ds). Then you can calc. responces to these generalized groups. But either such grouping will lead to dimensionality reduction or not depends on data themselves. But whether such grouping will lead to dim_reduction or not - depends on case/chance (on data).

PCA (also part of EDA) really aims for dimensionality reduction if you have tooo great quantity of features, extracting Principal Components that input into variety in ds. Also used for outliers removal in pre-modelling stage (as is before modelling dependencies). N.B. Non-Gaussian distributed data causes PCA to fail.